# How to compare two products based on their ratings?

Tags: statistics

I am interested in knowing how to calculate a ranking score from ratings of a product. E.g., take the apple appstore. There are two products A and B. Both have same average rating but 100 reviewers have rated A whereas 1000 reviewers have rated B. Intuitively it seems B should be ranked higher than A (it has lower standard error in the mean). Is there an established formula to compare two items and determine which is better based on their ratings?

Comment: See these links: - http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html - http://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-average-ratings.html - http://www.evanmiller.org/ranking-items-with-star-ratings.html on closer inspection of last link, he is just calculating `mean - standard error of the mean` and using that for ranking.

Answer (score 1):

I write some python code so you can run it easily.

```py
def score(nn):
  """ nn = [0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5] """
  if len(nn)==5:
    nn = [0, *nn]  # add 0
  N = sum(nn)
  K = 5
  kk = [1,2,3,4,5]
  z = 1.65  # alpha = 0.1  mean 95% confidence
  avg = sum(k*(nn[k]+1)/(N+K) for k in kk)
  diff = sum(k**2 * (nn[k]+1)/(N+K) for k in kk) \
       - sum(k    * (nn[k]+1)/(N+K) for k in kk) ** 2
  dev = z * sqrt(diff / (N+K+1))
  return avg - dev
```

You can just call it

```py
score([5, 5, 14, 48, 223])  # 4.517059350728805
```

Comment: can you explain your code? What are the parameters? Any reference to explanation of why your code is the correct approach?

Comment: I forgot where I took it from. The broad concept is, you find the average, and deduce for uncertainty by using the standard deviation. The result is the score that you are confident that the expected true rating is at least this score.